# Android: проблема с авторизацией в Twitter

Tags: oauth, android, java, twitter

Всем добрый день!
В процессе разработки приложения возникла необходимость авторизации в Twitter.
Нашел несколько примеров и один OpenSource клиент для Twitter. У него в активности LoginActivity реализован процесс авторизации который прекрасно работает! Я же решил заменить consumer_key и consumer_secret на свои, и меня возникает следующая ошибка:

```
winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException: java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null
```

То есть все проходит нормально, в браузере открывается окно с авторизацие напрямую указывающее на мой проект и после ввода данных происходит переход в окно моего приложения однако в этот момент выплывает эта ошибка!

Может кроме consumer_key и consumer_secret необходимо еще что-то указать?

Буду рад любой помощи!

Заранее всем большое спасибо!

Comment: А вы где взяли свой `consumer_key` и `consumer_secret`?

Comment: Здесь создал свое приложение:
https://dev.twitter.com/apps

Comment: о, черт, Твиттер - самая прибацаная соц. сеть в отношении API для Андроида    
Сам с ней с месяц назад долбался очень долго, могу посоветовать использовать библиотеку twitter4j и посочувствовать...

Comment: Спасибо! Сам это понял, и пришел к выводу что даже дело не в АПИ а в том что я ни черта не понимаю в самом твиттере! А так проблема решилась, тем что необходимо указывать в @Anywhere название пакета!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Попробуйте удалить приложение и установить заново. Либа возможно где-то в преференсах сохраняет старые токены
2. Поиграйте с CallBack_URI - его либо не должно быть или если он есть то уберите все ссылки на получение колбэк URL'а в коде

Comment: CallBack_URI у меня работает правильно, из браузера парсится в приложении! Я вроде нашел причину, но до конца не могу разобраться! В графе @Anywhere Domain как я понял нужно указать свой package из манифеста, но в каком формате не понятно!

Answer (score 0):

По поводу consumer token & key. Надо ещё изменять Customer token & key, которые приходят после авторизации в приложение.

Для шаринга картинок, сообщений и прочих операций использовал либу twitter4j 
Используйте http://twitter4j.org/.

Comment: customer/bearer token & key - они обычно после первой авторизации сохраняются в настройках аппы/либы - именно поэтому я рекомендовал удалить аппу. 

Кстати, оба что jTwitter что Twitter4J используют для авторизации одну и ту же либу. Twitter4J - мне он показался более кошерным :)

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под настройками апы/либы? Откуда и что удалить?

Comment: Преференсы имею в виду. Снесите аппу и заново установите - тогда обнулятся префы

Comment: Так я это делал неоднократно не помогает! Может Вы попробуете зарегистрировать апу в твиттер на пакет ru.mif.uldash а я попробую запустить с их использованием! Ведь надо где то указать значение пакета, во многих туториалах так написано!

Comment: Да а что такое CONSUMER_ID? У меня указано CONSUMER_ID = 1